# How to correctly access ArrayList to iterate over within HashMap Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am attempting to access an ArrayList within a HashMap and iterate over it. However I am currently running into an issue with the following setup.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");
map.put("key_one", list);

Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    log.info(pair.getKey());
    log.info(pair.getValue().getClass());
    for (String element : pair.getValue()) {
        log.info(element);
    }
}
```

There is something with accessing the ArrayList that is giving me issues.

**[ERROR]   required: array or java.lang.Iterable**

**[ERROR]   found:    java.lang.Object**

If I access the list outside of the map, everything works fine. Its just accessing within the HashMap.

Any guidance would be most appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Warm Regards

Comment: No, really, it's because you're using raw types. If you [ask the same question with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919831/how-do-you-iterate-over-inner-list-on-arrays-object-is-defining-as-arrays-aslis?noredirect=1#comment92749277_52919831), I'll close it for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate over a setup like that as follows:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> mapValue : map.entrySet()) {
    for (String listValue : mapValue.getValue()) {
        // Do stuff

    }
}
```

The reason your code is not working is because you're defining `pair` as `Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();`, without any types. This causes `pair.getValue()` to return `Object` and not some sort of `List`, which is why you cannot iterate over it in the for loop.

A fix using your code would be to change:

```
Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
```

to:

```
Map.Entry<String, List<String>> pair = (Map.Entry<String, List<String>>) it.next();
```

Comment: Minor detail, the OP could also define the `iterator` with the type info, `Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>> it...` and avoid the cast in `pair`.

Comment: (But if you are going to cast, refer to types consistently: `Map.Entry` on LHS vs `Entry` on RHS).

Comment: Thanks I've made it more consistent.

Comment: I ended up using the `Map.Entry<String, List<String>> pair = (Entry<String, List<String>>) it.next();` within the while loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just had to use generics in your code and then it works perfect. Here is your code with generics,

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");
map.put("key_one", list);

Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, List<String>> pair = it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey());
    System.out.println(pair.getValue().getClass());
    for (String element : pair.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the cast on the `it.next()` line any longer.

Comment: Oh yes, that was redundant. Thanks for pointing out.